# sweetaler2 import vuetify components

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, sweetalert2

I'm trying to create a sweetalert2 that that renders a component that uses vuetify elements, is that possible?

I have already tried using swal's HTML and that doesn't work

I want to be able to render a vuetify form component from a sweetalert2 pop-up.

Comment: You question is too broad. [mcve] is welcomed

Comment: Why not just use a Vuetify dialog? [Example with a form](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#form)

Comment: Im using the vuetify dialog, wasn't aware before a few hours ago. thank you